# What's the difference between '.toMatchObject' and 'objectContaining'

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have written the following test:

```
it('Can decrement the current step', function () {
    expect(reducer(TestState, { type: 'GOTO_PREVIOUS_STEP' })).toMatchObject({ currentStep: 4 });
});

it('Can decrement the current step v2', function () {
    expect(reducer(TestState, { type: 'GOTO_PREVIOUS_STEP' })).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ currentStep: 4 }));
});
```

both of them seem to pass the test, is there any difference between them? is there a performance impact between them?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

From looking at the docs, and my own experimentation to confirm it, the difference is in the handling of objects nested within the props passed as an expectation.

If the expectation object has a property, containing an object, which contains *some but not all* of the properties in the equivalent property of the actual object, then:

- `.toMatchObject()` will still pass, [as seen in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject).
- `expect.objectContaining()` will fail (unless you declare that property in the expectation object itself with `expect.objectContaining()`)

Examples (tested in Jest):

```
  // objectContaining, with nested object, containing full props/values
  // PASSES
  expect({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    position: {
      x: expect.any(Number),
      y: expect.any(Number)
    }
  }));

  // objectContaining, with nested object, containing partial props/values
  // FAILS
  expect({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    position: {
      x: expect.any(Number)
    }
  }));

  // objectContaining, with nested object, also declared with objectContaining, containing partial props/values
  // PASSES
  expect({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
    position: expect.objectContaining({
      x: expect.any(Number)
    })
  }));

  // toMatchObject, with nested object, containing full props/values
  // PASSES
  expect({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).toMatchObject({
    position: {
      x: expect.any(Number),
      y: expect.any(Number)
    }
  });

  // toMatchObject, with nested object, containing partial props/values
  // PASSES
  expect({ position: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).toMatchObject({
    position: {
      x: expect.any(Number)
    }
  });
```

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things"

Comment: Updated link to the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject

Comment: Great answer.  The names of these matchers is the opposite of what I initially thought they would be.

Answer (score 14):

My thinking is that `expect.objectContaining` (*and other matchers like it*) can be used instead of literal values inside the "object" you pass to other matchers.

This example is from the docs:

```js
test('onPress gets called with the right thing', () => {
  const onPress = jest.fn();
  simulatePresses(onPress);
  expect(onPress).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    x: expect.any(Number),
    y: expect.any(Number),
  }));
});
```

So, while they seem to do the same thing in your example, the `expect.*` ones are also useful in this other way.

Answer (score 9):

Even without functional differences between the two constructs, here's an example as to why `expect.objectContaining` - though long and cumbersome compared to `toMatchObject`, can be useful:

```
describe('list of X', () => {
  it('should contain an element with a specific ID', () => {
    const listOfItems = uut.getItems();
    expect(listOfItems).toContainEqual(expect.objectContaining({id: 'some-id'}));
  });
});
```

Even if `listOfItems` contains items as such (i.e. with fields other than just the 'id') --

```
[
  {id: 'some-id', other: 'fields'},
  {id: 'some-other-id', even: 'more-fields'}
]
```

still `expect.objectContaining` allows for a simple way of implementing the comparison as you'd expect (i.e. based strictly on the id); `toMatchObject` cannot be used here at all. So while `toMatchObject` is short and readable, the longer construct of the two is more generic and allows for greater flexibility as it can be utilized in ways that `toMatchObject()` can't.