# How to check for object properties match for an object using Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following code, that when called it returned an object. I want to write a test case that checks if the object has the tree property named accordingly and their value is number, array and bool.

Could you please provide an example using the Jest library?

```js
const location = () => {
  return {
    locationId: 5128581, // nyc usa
    geo: [-74.006, 40.7143],
    isFetching: false
  }
}

export default location
```

Comment: Are you using "jest" or "jestjs"? It seems both of those tags probably don't apply (see the hover-over for each one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between '.toMatchObject' and 'objectContaining'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692456/whats-the-difference-between-tomatchobject-and-objectcontaining)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try to use `expect.objectContaining()` and `expect.any()` to check each property type.

```
    import location from './whatever'
    describe('location', () => {
      it('should return location object', () => {
        expect(location()).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({
          locationId: expect.any(Number),
          geo: expect.any(Array),
          isFetching: expect.any(Boolean)
        }))
      })
    })
```