# How can I test part of object using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to test that time is parsed correctly and I am only interested in checking some of the properties and not the entire object. In this case hour and minutes.

I tried using `expect(object).toContain(value)` but as you can see in the snippet below it fails although the object contains the properties I am interested in and they have the correct value.

```
● Calendar > CalendarViewConfig › it should parse time

expect(object).toContain(value)

Expected object:
  {"display": "12:54", "full": 774, "hour": 12, "hours": 12, "minutes": 54, "string": "12:54"}
To contain value:
  {"hours": 12, "minutes": 54}

  67 |   it('it should parse time', () => {
  68 |     ...
> 69 |     expect(parseTime('12:54')).toContain({ hours: 12, minutes: 54})
  70 |   })

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/Views/Calendar/CalendarViewConfig.test.js:69:32)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between '.toMatchObject' and 'objectContaining'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692456/whats-the-difference-between-tomatchobject-and-objectcontaining)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

To check if expected object is a subset of the received object you need to use `toMatchObject(object)` method:

```
expect(parseTime('12:54')).toMatchObject({ hours: 12, minutes: 54})
```

or `expect.objectContaining(object)` matcher:

```
expect(parseTime('12:54')).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ hours: 12, minutes: 54}))
```

they works in slightly different ways, please take a look at [What's the difference between '.toMatchObject' and 'objectContaining'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692456/whats-the-difference-between-tomatchobject-and-objectcontaining) for details.

`toContain()` is designed to check that an item is in an array.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to test for part of an object *inside an array of objects*, use `objectContaining` within `arrayContaining`. Here's an example:

```
test( 'an object in an array of objects', async () => {
  const bookData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      book_id: 98764,
      book_title: 'My New International Book',
      country_iso_code: 'IN',
      release_date: '2022-05-24'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      book_id: 98764,
      book_title: 'My New International Book',
      country_iso_code: 'GB',
      release_date: '2022-05-31'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      book_id: 98764,
      book_title: 'My New International Book',
      country_iso_code: 'US',
      release_date: '2022-06-01'
    }
  ];

  expect( bookData ).toEqual( 
    expect.arrayContaining([ 
      expect.objectContaining(
        {
          country_iso_code: 'US',
          release_date: '2022-06-01'
        } 
      )
    ])
  );
} );
```

I got this from [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@andrei.pfeiffer/jest-matching-objects-in-array-50fe2f4d6b98).