# Jest : Testing for type or null

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a test where i want to test if my received object value types match a schema. Prob is that for some keys i may receive something or null

I tried this so far

```
  const attendeeSchema = {
  birthDate: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull("Date")),
  contact: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull(String)),
  createdAt: expect.any(Date),
  firstName: expect.any(String),
  id: expect.any(Number),
  idDevice: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull(Number)),
  information: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull(String)),
  lastName: expect.any(String),
  macAddress: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull(String)),
  updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
  // state: toBeTypeOrNull()
};

    const toBeTypeOrNull = (received, argument) => {
  const pass = expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(argument));
  if (pass || received === null) {
    return {
      message: () => `Ok`,
      pass: true
    };
  } else {
    return {
      message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${argument} type or null`,
      pass: false
    };
  }
};
```

and on my test

```
 expect(res.result.data).toBe(attendeeSchema);
```

i also tried tobeEqual and other stuff....

my test doenst pass with

```
TypeError: any() expects to be passed a constructor function. Please pass one or use anything() to match any object.
```

I have no idea what to do here..
If someone has an idea
Thanks

Comment: Can you precise which line of your code originally triggers the error? You have many calls to `any` here..

Comment: I dont really know the line cause the error doesnt give me a precise one, but if i just keep one line of my attendeeschema i still have the same error. Error says line 3 of my schema file which is  const pass = expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(argument));

Answer (score 13):

All the previously given responses improperly use `expect()` in their implementation, so they don't really work.

What you want is a jest matcher that works like `any()` but accepts null values and doesn't use `expect()` functions in its implementation. You can implement this as an extension by basically copying the original `any()` implementation (from [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/asymmetric_equality/Any.js)), but with a null test added to the start:

```
expect.extend({
  nullOrAny(received, expected) {
    if (received === null) {
      return {
        pass: true,
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected) }, but received ${ this.utils.printReceived(received) }`
      };
    }

    if (expected == String) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'string' || received instanceof String,
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected) }, but received ${ this.utils.printReceived(received) }`
      };        
    }

    if (expected == Number) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'number' || received instanceof Number,
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      };
    }

    if (expected == Function) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'function' || received instanceof Function,
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      };
    }

    if (expected == Object) {
      return {
        pass: received !== null && typeof received == 'object',
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      };
    }

    if (expected == Boolean) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'boolean',
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      };
    }

    /* jshint -W122 */
    /* global Symbol */
    if (typeof Symbol != 'undefined' && this.expectedObject == Symbol) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'symbol',
        message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      };
    }
    /* jshint +W122 */

    return {
      pass: received instanceof expected,
      message: () => `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
    };
  }
});
```

throw the above in a `.js` file, then point to that file with the jest [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) configuration variable. Now you can run your tests like:

```
const schema = {
  person: expect.nullOrAny(Person),
  age: expect.nullOrAny(Number)
};

expect(object).toEqual(schema);
```

Comment: The link to the jasmine doc does not exists anymore. Here is the new one: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/src/core/asymmetric_equality/Any.js

Answer (score 7):

Adding on the previous two answers a more common approach would be to wrap the core matcher in a try/catch block

```
expect.extend({
  toBeTypeOrNull(received, classTypeOrNull) {
      try {
          expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(classTypeOrNull));
          return {
              message: () => `Ok`,
              pass: true
            };
      } catch (error) {
          return received === null 
            ? {
                  message: () => `Ok`,
                  pass: true
              }
            : {
                  message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${classTypeOrNull} type or null`,
                  pass: false
            };
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: IMO This should be the accepted answer, because `expect.any(null)` will return an error, which needs to be catched, well done

Answer (score 6):

You can use `toBeOneOf` from [jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#tobeoneofmembers).

After you have installed `jest-extended` to make `expect.toBeOneOf` available:

```js
const attendeeSchema = {
  birthDate: expect.toBeOneOf([expect.any(Date), null]),
  contact: expect.toBeOneOf([expect.any(String), null]),
  createdAt: expect.any(Date),
  firstName: expect.any(String),
  id: expect.any(Number),
  idDevice: expect.toBeOneOf([expect.any(Number), null]),
  information: expect.toBeOneOf([expect.any(String), null]),
  lastName: expect.any(String),
  macAddress: expect.toBeOneOf([expect.any(String), null]),
  updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
};
```

```js
expect(res.result.data).toEqual(attendeeSchema);
```

Answer (score 4):

I actually don't know Jest at all, but I took a look because code testing interests me at the moment.

From what i see in the [expect.extend documentation](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectextendmatchers) it seems that you are using it the wrong way. You are currently giving it the result of the call to `toBeTypeOrNull`, for example in `birthDate: expect.extend(toBeTypeOrNull("Date")),` not the function itself. This probably causes the call to have an undefined argument because it's declared with 2 arguments `(received, argument)`. `argument` is then undefined and you can't do `expect.any(argument)` inside your custom function.

From what i see in the docs, you are supposed to call `extend` at the beginning with an object which contains all your custom functions so you can use them later. Try this code and don't hesitate to comment if something goes wrong:

**Update:** for the differences between `objectContaining` and `toMatchObject`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876473/7393478)

```
expect.extend({
  toBeTypeOrNull(received, argument) {
    const pass = expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(argument));
    if (pass || received === null) {
      return {
        message: () => `Ok`,
        pass: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${argument} type or null`,
        pass: false
      };
    }
  }
});

//your code that starts the test and gets the data
  expect(res.result.data).toMatchObject({
    birthDate: expect.toBeTypeOrNull(Date),
    contact: expect.toBeTypeOrNull(String),
    createdAt: expect.any(Date),
    firstName: expect.any(String),
    id: expect.any(Number),
    idDevice: expect.toBeTypeOrNull(Number),
    information: expect.toBeTypeOrNull(String),
    lastName: expect.any(String),
    macAddress: expect.toBeTypeOrNull(String),
    updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
    // state: toBeTypeOrNull()
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your work on this ! I tried your code, but toBeTypeOrNull is not a function in my test. That is weird cause its exactly how its done in the docs

Comment: after another look to the docs, i think you could try with the `objectContaining` or `toMatchObject` functions, as your `attendeeSchema` is not a type, but an object, updated the answer so that the second part is the test itself instead of an object.

Comment: Its not working. And actually even the jest docs is not working. I tried  expect({apples: 6, bananas: 3}).toEqual({
    apples: expect.toBeDivisibleBy(2),
    bananas: expect.not.toBeDivisibleBy(2),
  }); And toBeDivisibleBy(2) is not a function. I have no idea how i can solve this

Comment: I'll try to test it directly before I do another update, but that's not for right now, as I entered a busy part. If you find something i'm interested ;)

Comment: Well i checked the doc and they say that this is not supposed to be something that you should test... so that s why they didnt add anything to do so. I gave up and what i do now is testing that my object contains the key i want, whatever the type .

Comment: `if ( pass ... ) ` fails type checking with `An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making specific handler I decided to make a general "any of":

```
expect.extend({
  toEqualAnyOf(received: any, argument: any[]) {
    const found = argument.some((eqItem) => {
      // undefined
      if (typeof eqItem === 'undefined' && typeof received === 'undefined') {
        return true;
      }
      // null
      if (eqItem === null && received === null) {
        return true;
      }
      // any expect.<any> or direct value
      try {
        expect(received).toEqual(eqItem);
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    });
    return found
      ? {
          message: () => 'Ok',
          pass: true,
        }
      : {
          message: () => `expected ${received} to be any of ${argument}`,
          pass: false,
        };
  },
});

module.exports = { expect };
```

And it can be used like this:

```
const userImageSchema = {
  displayName: expect.any(String),
  // null or undefined or part of structure or instance of a class
  image: expect.toEqualAnyOf([
    null,
    undefined,
    expect.objectContaining({
      type: 'Buffer',
      data: expect.any(Array),
    }),
    expect.any(ImageClass),
  ]),
  orgs: expect.any(Array),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something to validate any type or `null` and came across this answer, which was 95% right. The problem was in the line as the expectation was failing trying to compare `null` with `argument`.

```
const pass = expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(argument));
```

And as a bonus, I have a created `toBeObjectContainingOrNull`. Here is my code:

```
const expect = require("expect");

const okObject = {
    message: () => "Ok",
    pass: true
};

expect.extend({
    toBeTypeOrNull(received, argument) {
        if (received === null)
            return okObject;
        if (expect(received).toEqual(expect.any(argument))) {
            return okObject;
        } else {
            return {
                message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${argument} type or null`,
                pass: false
            };
        }
    },
    toBeObjectContainingOrNull(received, argument) {
        if (received === null)
            return okObject;

        const pass = expect(received).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(argument));
        if (pass) {
            return okObject;
        } else {
            return {
                message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${argument} type or null`,
                pass: false
            };
        }
    }
});

module.exports = { expect };
```

Then you can use `toBeObjectContainingOrNull` as follows:

```
const userImageSchema = {
    displayName: expect.any(String),
    image: expect.toBeObjectContainingOrNull({
        type: "Buffer",
        data: expect.any(Array)
    }),
    orgs: expect.any(Array)
};
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Already implemented in expect-more-jest

This will work:

```
require('expect-more-jest');

test("test 1 2 3", async () => {
    expect(null).toBeNullableOf(String)
    expect('String').toBeNullableOf(expect.any(String))
    expect('String').not.toBeNullableOf(expect.any(Number))
    expect('String').toBeNullableOf('String')
    expect(1).toBeNullableOf(expect.any(Number))
    expect(1).not.toBeNullableOf(expect.any(String))
    expect(1).not.toBeNullableOf(String)
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the posted issue. We need to be able to declare an object's property as being `null` or something else. The code you posted works on the value passed to `expect`.

Comment: @DannyHurlburt I see... I thought that it would be good enough to do something like `expect(obj.name).toBeNullableOf(String)`

Answer (score 0):

my solution is simply to modify input data before running 'expect' statement, example:

schema value should look like this:

```js
const attendeeSchema = {
  ....
  contact: true,
};
```

in test, before expect, we modify input data to check if the value is string or null:

```js
res.result.data = res.result.data.map(i => ({...i, contact: typeof i.contact === 'string' || i.contact === null}))
expect(res.result.data).toBe(attendeeSchema);
```