# How to use jest extend function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I want to use `extend` to create a custom function (`nullOrAny`) that will check if value contains either *string* or *null*. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, I tried different methods from different site, but none of them helped.

Setting up a custom function has no problem, except when I try to use it. The typescript doesn't seem to recognize the function, and also it's not included in the hint or suggestion while I'm typing (see image below). [the code below was from here stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133367/jest-testing-for-type-or-null)

[image]

It showed this typescript error.

> Property 'nullOrAny' does not exist on type 'Expect'.

I think this must be some config problem, someone can help me figure it out how to achieve this? I would appreciate comments also.

---

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['./test'],
  testRegex: '(/__test__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./**/*.js', './**/*.ts'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./utils/singleton.ts']
}
```

**singleton.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { mockDeep, mockReset, DeepMockProxy } from 'jest-mock-extended'

import prisma from './client'

jest.mock('./client', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
}))

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(prismaMock)
})

expect.extend({
  nullOrAny(received, expected) {
    if (received === null) {
      return {
        pass: true,
        message: () =>
          `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(
            expected
          )}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      }
    }

    if (expected == Number) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received == 'number' || received instanceof Number,
        message: () =>
          `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(
            expected
          )}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      }
    }

    // ... more code here

    return {
      pass: received instanceof expected,
      message: () =>
        `expected null or instance of ${this.utils.printExpected(
          expected
        )}, but received ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
    }
  }
})

export const prismaMock = prisma as unknown as DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>
```

**sample.test.ts**

```
it('should return the expected body object properties for pagination', () => {
  // expect(res._getJSONData()).toMatchObject(payload)

  expect(res._getJSONData()).toMatchObject({
    page: expect.nullOrAny(Number),
  })
})
```